# MISRA-C: cast literal number

Tags: c, misra

I read a source code,
there is a statement like:
uint32 XYZ;
...
XYZ = (uint32)0x0000000U.

I wonder if the cast is necessary, is XYZ = 0U OK?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The integer constant `0U` can in theory be an unsigned int of 64 bits. If so, the cast is necessary since MISRA-C (2012 10.3) does not allow implicit conversion to a narrower type. However, the cast isn't necessary on 32 bit CPUs and smaller.

An alternative is to write `uint32_t XYZ = UINT32_C(0);` in which case the compiler picks the appropriate type for the integer constant automatically.